# Insert/inject string to html string

Tags: javascript, html

I'm fetching some html from the server which comes back as a string, but I need to insert a `target='_blank'` to all `<a>` tags within the html string. Is there a better or more efficient way to do this other than looping through the entire string to look for `<a` and then inserting `target='_blank'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the [`.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method, using regex.

```js
var string = "<a href='https://stackoverflow.com/'>Stack Overflow</a><br><a href='https://google.com/'>Google</a><br><a href='https://wikipedia.com'>Wikipedia</a>";

var newString = string.replace(/<a/g, "<a target='_blank'");

document.body.innerHTML = newString;
```

Comment: What about the case where the `a` already has a `target` attribute? Like `_self` for example

Comment: You can use `string.replace(/<a target='_[^]*'/g, "<a target='_blank'");`.

Comment: You can use `string.replace(/<a target='_[^]*'/g, "<a target='_blank'");`.

Answer (score 1):

First place the HTML into your page. Then immediately run code which modifies the DOM elements to include the needed attribute.

For example if you are placing the html into a container element with an id of `container`:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('#container a').forEach(element => {
  element.setAttribute('target', '_blank')
})
```

```html
<div id="container">
     <a href="http://google.com">Google</a>
     <a href="http://wikipedia.com">Wikipedia</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create an html element with the html code that comes back as a string, then `getElementsByTagName('a')` and finally set the `target` attribute to be `"_blank"`, for example:

```js
let string = `<ul><li><a href="http://example.com/1">Link 1</a></li><li><a href="http://example.com/2">Link 2</a></li><li><a href="http://example.com/3">Link 3</a></li></ul>`;

var el = document.createElement("html");
el.innerHTML = string;
    
let anchors = el.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (let anchor of anchors) {
  anchor.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
}

console.log(el.innerHTML);

document.body.innerHTML = el.innerHTML;
```

Remember to use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) ` to escape the double and single quotes of your html string.

Answer (score 1):

```
//if you want to do it in a string;
response.replace(/<a/g, '<a target="_blank" ');

//if object (html)
//first append it to DOM
let container = document.querySelector(".container");
container.innerHTML = response;
container.querySelectorAll("a").forEach(el => el.setAttribute('target', '_blank'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't complicate htmlStrings more than they already are. Use this one liner after HTML has been rendered:

```
[...document.links].forEach(a => a.target = '_blank');
```

- [`document.links`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/links) is a little known property that will collect all `<a>` into a HTML Collection.
- [The bracket and spread operator `\[...\]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Syntax) wrapped around the HTML Collection converts it into a real Array.
- [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) executes a callback function on each link within the Array.
- The callback function simply adds the [`.target` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Attributes) to each link and assigns them the value of `"_blank"`.

---

#### Demo

```js
[...document.links].forEach(a => a.target = '_blank');

// Just to check if each link is correctly modified
console.log([...document.links].map(a => a.outerHTML));
```

```css
a {
  font: 700 3vw/1.45 Verdana;
  display: block;
  width: max-content;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  text-decoration: none
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.as-console-wrapper {
  width: 80%;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin-left: 20%;
}
```

```html
<a href='example.com'>LINK</a>
<a href='example.com'>LINK</a>
<a href='example.com'>LINK</a>
<a href='example.com'>LINK</a>
```